# How To Move Picsart and Phonto Fonts To A New Phone

Tags: applications, data-transfer, samsung-smart-switch

I have two apps on my phone (PicsArt & Phonto) that can handle fonts on images.

It took me a long time to install fonts on these apps, especially the non-English fonts.

My old phone was Samsung A70, and the new one is Samsung Galaxy Note 9. They have Android 9 and Android 10, respectively.

I seamlessly moved most of the staff from A70 to Note90 using the SmartSwitch app. However, the related data for these two apps have not been moved.

I tried to find the related folders that contain these apps' data to copy them, but it did not work for Phonto and no such folders in the PicsArt case. I could not find any solution on the Internet either.

Note: The PicsArt on the new phone will not even let me install the fonts again without subscribing and paying for this feature.

So, is there a way to move my old fonts for these two apps, especially the PicsArt?
What can I do to avoid the re-searching and reinstallation hassle for hundreds of fonts one by one?